# Gitflow with Semver Patch/Minor Update to Earlier Tag

Tags: git, version-control, versioning, git-flow, semantic-versioning

What is the gitflow process/flow to apply a patch or minor update to a previously released version/tag (using semver)?

For Example:

> Software's master/main branch has the latest tag/version of v2.0.0; however, a patch/minor update needs to be applied to version v1.0.0 which should make the latest update of v1 of the software at v1.0.1. The patch/minor update must also be applied to v2.0.0 making the latest tag on master v0.2.1.

Comment: >The patch/minor update must also be applied to v2.0.0 making the latest tag on master v0.2.1.

Did you mean v2.0.1 on that last version?  I am not entirely sure I understand your question, did you ever settle on an answer?